# Buildings missing texture in 3d web scene exported from ArcScene

Tags: export, 3d, arcscene, cityengine, web-scene

A random sampling of buildings are missing textures. The models were made in Sketchup 8 and exported to COLLADA, then dropped in ArcScene. All of the textures are .jpg files. The models look fine in ArcScene the issue is only in the exported web scene.